# Can I use <br> or similar in <td> to avoid RowSpan?

Tags: php, html, css

I am using PHP to generate a report, which is basically a one line table.

However, if any of the fields reflect a memo then I would like to see multiple lines of memo text - with line breaks of some kid - and not just the whole memo text as one long string.

I am using PHP to generate the HHTML. I did try replacing all `'\r\n'` with `<br>`, but that didn't work.

To do it 'properly' is going to get messy. I need to examine all fields in the table and find the memo field with the most line breaks, then use the number of lines to add a `rowspan` to each`<td>` in the table.

Is there any easy way to avoid that?

Bad ascii art clarification follows. I currently have

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| edit box text | radio group selection | memo line 1 memo line 2 ... memo line x | 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and what I want is:

```
------------------------------------------------------
| edit box text | radio group selection | memo line 1 |
|               |                       | memo line 2 | 
|               |                       |    ...      | 
|               |                       | memo line x | 
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Sounds like the TDs have kind of "nowrap" applied?

Comment: When you say the `\r\n` and `<br />` was ineffective, were they output at all or as text? Perhaps you could show a sample of the code and/or output.

Comment: Post the HTML output of your code block please - i'm guessing you have a structure problem.

Comment: Are the memo lines coming from a database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about do it like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>edit box text</td>
    <td>radio group selectio</td>
    <td>
      <div>
        memo line 1
      </div>
      <div>
        memo line 2
      </div>
      <div>
        memo line 3
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

combining tables with div like this , you kept your table and forced the "memo"s to take a new line, and using this formation, you can give the memos a different styles.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is over simplifying it, but why don't you just assign a fixed width to the table cell with the memo? I forget if `<td>`s can act funny with width set, but if so just wrap it in a div with fixed width.

OR with php...

[wordwrap() — Wraps a string to a given number of characters](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php)

OR with CSS  or a `<pre>` tag if it's already formatted:

```
td.has_memo {
    white-space:pre;
}
```

OR again, with php if it's preformatted:

[nl2br() — Inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Comment: +1 wordwrap() inserts \n.  I suspect this is an HTML question, not really PHP

Comment: Actually wordwrap() lets you use anything you want for a line break in the third argument. You never explained if the text was preformatted or not, why does option 1 not work for you, if not the others?

Comment: True, Wordwrap() let's me insert any characters I want - but what would you suggest? It already has \r\n in it. And as to the line length, that would have to be strpos($memoText, '\r\n'), so WordWrap does not seem to be getting me anywhere, unless I am missing something.  As I said elsewhere, I think I should be looking at HTML rather than the PHP which generates it, in order to find how to get multiple lines in a <td> without using RowSpand

Comment: @Mawg: What about the html and css solutions I offered? The first one seems to me like a no-brainer, set a width on the `<td>` with the memo text or use `pre` formatting. Am I missing something? Is the text preformatted the way you want it displayed or not? What is wrong with `<td style="width:200px">` or something?

Comment: @Mawg, nvm I see you got a solution! GL

Answer (score 0):

maybe this might work

```
<td valign="top">
```

Comment: I doubt that that would achieve what I want (see bad ascii art). The memo text does contain \r\n and I want that reflected on the screen

Answer (score 0):

Simply clear the formatting (if any) on the cell that needs to show the memo field.

Then print out the contents like this:

```
echo nl2br($Fields["MemoField"]);
```

The above function auto-converts all \n lines to br tags.

Hope this helps.